# powershell equivalent of `netsh http show sslcert ipport='0.0.0.0:8172'`

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm hoping to make some idempotent pre-flight checks and I'd like to test before clobbering SSL Certs. [Netsh seems to be deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/networking/technologies/netsh/netsh),

> "...It is recommended that you use Windows PowerShell to manage
>   networking technologies in Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 rather
>   than Network Shell..."

and I'm hoping to just use powershell modules to configure IIS.
I've been able to find:

---

`Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding` to replace `netsh http add sslcert ipport='0.0.0.0:8172'...`

---

but unable to find anything like:

---

`Get-NetIPHttpsCertBinding` to replace `netsh http show sslcert ipport='0.0.0.0:8172'...`

---

Is there some code syntax/method I'm best recommended to use?

Comment: If `Get-NetIPHttpsConfiguration` doesn't show it, then it might be due to a limitation of the MSFT_NetIpHTTPsConfiguration CIM class, which only supports `AddCertBinding` and `RemoveCertBinding` methods.  Even the [Get-SslCertificateBinding script on powershellgallery.com](http://powershellgallery.com/packages/Carbon/1.9.0/Content/Certificates/Get-SslCertificateBinding.ps1) still relies on `netsh.exe http show sslcert`.  Regardless, check-out this [possible work-around](https://techstronghold.com/blogs/scripting/powershell-script-to-get-all-iis-bindings-and-ssl-certificates).

Comment: "Netsh is on its way out" - reference needed.

Comment: Netsh is still Windows Server 2019, and in all other insider editions I have as well as Windows insider clients. So, I too am wondering why one would say "Netsh is on its way out". Especailly, after  MS has stated the all cmd.exe/DOS stuff will be in the OS for the forseeable future, as they have sado for Windows PowerShell. Sure , no more new work going into them, but they'll be there. Yet, sure, they want all using PowerShell instead.

Comment: Despite the document recommend to use powershell command but it seems that Microsoft haven't release a workaround powershell command. Netsh http show sslcert is still the only way to show all ssl cert bindings. IISadministration can only be used to display IIS https binding and its cert. Now that the document say network shell is still supported, I think you could keep using net shell.

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e74d2e17-7cd9-4da6-b0ad-782a6c783e04/netsh-to-soon-be-deprecated?forum=w81previtpro "In future versions of windows, microsoft might remove the netsh functionality for TCP/IP.

Microsoft recommends taht you transition to Windows Powershell if you currently
use netsh to configure and manage TCP/IP"

Comment: Documentation says use of `netsh` is supported.

Answer (score -2):

To add a port binding, use `Add-NetIPHttpsCertBinding`. Theoretically. It appears that this applet is not easy to work with. If you use the `netsh http add sslcert` command instead, it might indicate failure (file already exists), but when I tried it, it adds the binding anyway.

In order to list or remove a port try the following.

```
Import-Module WebAdministration;

$ipPort = 0.0.0.0:4002;

$result = Get-ChildItem -path IIS:\SSLbindings\$ipPort;
$result = Remove-Item -path IIS:\SSLbindings\$ipPort;
```

As long as WebAdministration is imported these should work fine.